# async.series: wait for client connected

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I've already read the async documentation but I'm quite new to (node)js and I'm not sure about the right approach.

I have a server:

```
var client;
var connected = false;

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.setEncoding("utf8");
    client = socket;

    connected = true;
    console.log("Connected");

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        // do something
    });

    socket.on("close", function() {
        console.log("close");
    });
});
```

then I have an async series. I want to wait until a client connects (i.e. `connected == true`).

```
async.series([
    function one(next_step) {
        // do something
        next_step(null);
    }, 

    // wait for connected
    function wait_for_client(next_step) {
        async.until(
            function () { return connected == true; },
            function (cb) { setTimeout(cb, 10); }, 
            function (err) { console.log("exit"); next_step(null); }
        );
    },

    function three(next_step) {
        // do something
        next_step(null);
    },

    // 
}
```

I'm not sure how to "wait" inside step two until connected changes.
A while cycle will block the process or async takes care of it?

What's the best way to wait for an external event inside an async.series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using async.until(test, fn, callback).
From the docs:

> until(test, fn, callback)
>
> Repeatedly call fn until test returns true. Calls callback when
>   stopped, or an error occurs. callback will be passed an error and any
>   arguments passed to the final fn's callback.

- Your test would be connected == true.
- Fn could be a retry to
  connect, if your server has this functionality.
- Then you can call the
  series's callback inside until's callback.

Comment: I edited the first post, trying to insert the async.until(). It tests the condition and executes the fn() only once. If I call the cb() inside fn I run out of stack, of course. I don't see the correct syntax.

Comment: Solved: I need to set a timeout to avoid the stack overflow.